# Running a command with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have seen another question like this one, but I can't get it to work. I would like my visual basic program to run the command prompt, and run the command ipconfig. Right now, I am trying `Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd", "ipconfig")`, but it only opens the command prompt and doesn't run ipconfig. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k ipconfig")
```

you can try this

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you explain what the /k flag does.

Comment: I tried to, but it said that I had to wait a few minutes. I was going to wait, click the check mark, then delete my comment.

Comment: @EricJ. the /k flag runs the command requested but leaves the command and window open instead of closing after the command has run.